# database attachement when creating .jar file

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jar, database-connection

I have created a desktop application of shop management system and it is working well (runs on ide) but when I created a jar file of it and run this on another computer then it is not doing anything.

The problem which I figure it out is that the database is not attached with the .jar file.

Can anybody guide me?

Details:
Language : java
IDE: netbeans
Database: mysql server 5.1

Comment: is there any error log you can share with us? thanks

Comment: No there no such things. but when i make a .jar file of it, the file is saved in the C:\Users\SK\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ShopManagementSystem\dist directory with a lib folder and and a .txt file but no db file

Comment: It seems that you need to install mysql in this other computer (if it can't access the same mysql your IDE is accessing) and put the data there.

Comment: you can also use an embedded db like sharp edge suggests down below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Mysql server doesn't support db Embedding feature.
You may consider changing the DBMS If you want to ship your database with the application.
[apache derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)
[h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html)
and sun's distribution of [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html)
These will help your current scenario or if you have simple light weight operations, You can use SQLite.

Comment: SQlite didn't require such things?

Comment: You can ship the SQLite database with your jar file
You can either put the jar in your webapp/WEB-INF/lib folder or in your application lib folder.

Comment: If you have got basic add, update, delete and select operations with primitive values (No images or files) then you can use SQLite for your desktop application. Or you can go to that shop and install Mysql server on that system.